# Software integrity check

Tags: c#

I would like to implement a check on program start, that would search for all referenced modules (dlls, exes), then check their versions and presence.

Then if something goes wrong, display a message box with problem description and close.

I'm currently using Reflection, but the problem now is that some modules are loaded before I'm able to do any checks (before Main()) and the program crashes.

The only solution I see now is to write pre-loader app, that would do just that and then launch the main program.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can strong sign all the DLLs and EXEs you need to verify.

Comment: If your app is installed from an MSI, you can build it such that the Windows Installer service does all the checks to confirm that files are there with the correct version numbers and Registry keys are built as well. (Just be sure to package such that each file you want to check is its own component and key.)

Comment: To Oded and ewall: 
I need a possibility to display custom message at runtime if something goes wrong (say, dll is not found). Your suggestions does not solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Your assemblies will be loaded before you can run your checks if they are referenced by the assembly/executable that contains the checking code.  As far as I know, the only way around this (besides a pre-loader app as you mentioned) is to remove all references from your entry point assembly/executable and then load them using reflection based on configuration.